# Strange sum notation

Tags: multisets, index-notation

I have the following sum and I would like to generalize the notation but I don't see how to choose i index...

$$
-2P(A_{1} \cap A_{2}) - 2P(A_{1} \cap A_{3}) - 2P(A_{2} \cap A_{3}) = -2\sum_{i=something}^{something} P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})
$$

thanks ;)

Comment: What's the rule for when the summand gets a minus and when it gets a plus?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, they are all minus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to sum all possibile combinations of two events, then using a double summation will do the trick:

$$\sum_{i,j\\ i\neq j}P(A_i\cap A_j)=\sum_{i}\sum_{j,\ j\neq i}P(A_i\cap A_j)$$

Comment: ahh ok thanks! it was easyer than expected

Comment: but here order matters, right ? I mean there will be A1A2 and A2A1, no?

Comment: $A_i\cap A_j=A_j\cap A_i$ as $\cap$ is symmetric.